# Chef - Change files group recursively

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, centos7, chef-recipe, chgrp

I have the following structure:

/opt/conf/files.txt

What I'm trying to achieve is:

```
sudo chgrp -R tomcat conf
```

Change all the files in the 'conf' directory to the group 'tomcat'

I tried this:

```
directory "/opt/conf" do
  group 'tomcat'
  mode '0070'
  recursive true
end
```

but it just change the group to tomcat but not the files inside the conf directory.

How can achieve to change all the content of the conf directory using recipes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not something the `directory` resource supports. You'll have to use `chown` or `chgrp` in an `execute` resource. There is a good reason for this, I promise, but it's a long and winding tale of convergent ontologies.